# terminate bat script in absence of another running process

Tags: script, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'd like a .bat script I am running to only run while another process is running (an .exe that is running).

What command can I use to make my script check for another process periodically (say every 5 seconds), and in the absence of that process, shut itself down?

The current script I have simply kills some processes that interfere with a game, and launch a couple of other scripts that I use for hot keys etc.THis little script I wrote just helps start & stop all this peripheral scripts once the game is launched/killed

```
@echo off

mode con: cols=80 lines=41

taskkill /f /im bio4.exe
taskkill /f /im RTrainer.exe
taskkill /f /im RE4_Min_Max.exe
taskkill /f /im trainer-hotkeys.exe

start steam://rungameid/254700
start /d "D:\Windows_Games\Steam Games\common\Resident Evil 4\TRAINER" RTrainer.exe

start /d "C:\Users\James\Documents\My-SCRIPTS" RE4_Min_Max.exe
start /d "C:\Users\James\Documents\My-SCRIPTS" trainer-hotkeys.exe


echo (new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")).AppActivate("Resident Evil 4"); > focus.js
cscript //nologo focus.js
del focus.js

color A
cls

:BEGIN
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                             Launching RE4UHD
echo.
echo                          Press any to interrupt........
timeout 5 >nul
cls
:END


color A
cls

echo.
echo                     press any to terminate RE4UHD and Scripts

for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /b ::: "%~f0"') do @echo(%%A
pause >nul 2>&1

taskkill /f /im bio4.exe
taskkill /f /im RTrainer.exe
taskkill /f /im RE4_Min_Max.exe
taskkill /f /im trainer-hotkeys.exe


color E
cls

echo.
echo                     Game and Scripts successfully terminated

ping 45 >nul 2>&1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `tasklist` and query for `IMAGENAME eq`.

Comment: ok that seems to get me the name of my running process, but I cant see how that is going to terminate the process..Am I missing something? the name of the process is bio4.exe

Comment: also I dont see how that uses any kind of timeout as I requested to know how to use that.

Comment: *how that is going to terminate the process* Use `FOR /F` over `taskkill` and, if not found, use `GOTO :EOF`. *how that uses any kind of timeout* It is a separate task. Use `ping` to some non-existed address with proper timeout, for example...

Comment: sorry. I guess Im  too novice for this.  I dont understand how to put all of that together. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [test.bat]

```vb
@echo off 
REM Initializing commands
:loop
REM Repeated commands
ping -n 1 -w 5000 192.168.255.254 > nul
REM If available then replace previous line with 
REM TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
for /f %%a in ('tasklist ^| find "MyEXE.EXE"') do if "%%a"=="MyEXE.EXE" goto :loop
REM Finalizing commands
```

Comment: ok i have edited my question to include the original script. Now I need to know where to insert the code you have shown. I have tired putting it in between different places but it doesn't have the desired effect. I am hoping this command can keep running even if there are other parts of the script waiting for key input. Thank you!

Comment: @KalamalkaKid What process must be checked for it is running? your script starts and terminates a lot of processes...

Comment: the script first checks to see if any of the processes are running then kils any instances of them.. The task I want it to check for is  bio4.exe .Essentially I want the script to shut down all the processes and close if bio.exe isnt running (beacuse it crashed).

Comment: almost there! I added it after ':END' and it continues the script. I think I can continue from here. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Ok. If `timeout` is available (as I see in your script) then replace `ping` line in my script with `TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK` line.

Comment: one last thing. Is there a line of code I could insert that would allow a key press to exit the loop and jump to another line of code?Presently the script is stuck in the loop if bio4.exe is active. Id like the option to exit the loop with a keystroke. Cheers!

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Use `CHOICE`.

Comment: I'd do `ping -n 6 127.0.0.1` to wait for `5` seconds, because your IP address `192.168.255.154` might be (in)valid on different systems. And I'd let `tasklist` do the (case-insensitive) filtering for the correct process name: `for /F "skip=2" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "ImageName eq MyEXE.exe"') do goto :loop` (the loop will not execute when no process `MyEXE.exe` is found)...